# Can i set my created channels permisions like only my staff role can edit or delete it. My code so far:

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want my staff role can edit, delete this created channel.

```js
client.on('message', message =>{
if (!message.content.startsWith('*open-channel')) return;  //This line for some bug happens in my bot
if (message.channel.id !== '759430340972118026') return;   // I set a channel for the users can only use 
                                                           //this command in
if(message.author.bot || message.channel.type === "dm") return; //For bugs again
if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'OWNER')) {               //This command only 
                                                                                    //for owner role now.
      return message.reply('You should be OWNER for using this command.').then(message => {
message.delete({ timeout: 8000 })
})
}
  const messageArray = message.content.split(' ');
const cmd = messageArray[0];
const args = messageArray.slice(1).join(' ').toUpperCase();
  if (message.content.startsWith('*open-channel'))
var kanal = message.guild.channels.create(`${args} - ${message.author.tag}`,{type : 'voice'})
.then(channel => channel.setParent(message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "USER CHANNELS"))); //setParent moves my channel to choosen catagory. And 'args - message.author.tag'  is channel name
                                                          
  message.channel.send("Its done now buddy :3");

})
```

Sorry for my bad english if i wrote something wrong. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GuildChannelManager.create.options.permissionOverwrites()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create). Also, you can set the channel parent directly when creating it.

```js
message.guild.channels.create(`${args} - ${message.author.tag}`, {
 type: 'voice',
 permissionOverwrites: [
  {
   id: '<Staff Role ID>',
   allow: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS'],
  },
 ],
 parent: message.guild.channels.cache.find(
  (channel) => channel.name === 'USER CHANNELS'
 ),
});
```